# check input field for special character or forbid certain characters

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, unicode

I want to check input username for correct input.
First Problem: i have many users in east europe, so special characters must be inside. Some Users choose email as username, some (it is a database for dogs) choose their kennelname which can also contain an apostrophe.

I am using Just Validate / javascript for first checking.

I tried

```js
const validation = new JustValidate('#form');

validation
  .addField('#username', [
    {
      rule: 'minLength',
      value: 3,
      errorMessage: '<?=$translation_form_too_short?>',
    },
    {
      rule: 'maxLength',
      value: 30,
      errorMessage: '<?=$translation_form_too_long?>',
    },
    
    {
    rule: 'customRegexp',
    value: /[a-zA-ZÁáÀàÂâÃãÄäĂăĀāÅåĄąÆæÉéÈèÊêËëĚěĒēĖėĘęÍíÌìÎîÏïĪīĮįIıÓóÒòÔôÕõÖöŐőØøÚúÙùÛûÜüŰűŪūůYÝýĆćČčçĎďĐđĐðĢģĞğĶķŁłĻļŃńÑñŇňŅņŊŋŘřŚśŠšŞşßŤťŦŧÞþŢţŻżŹźŽž\s\d@.-]+/gu,
    errorMessage: '<?=$translation_register_username_condition?>!',
    
  },
```

too long / short works fine but regex don´t.

Same regex with html pattern, also not working.

with

```js
  document.getElementById("username").onkeypress = function(e) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (">)(<[#*+;/\"".indexOf(chr) >= 0)
        return false;
};
```

i can't insert f.e. É (on german keyboard).

Allowed should be all latin letters, digits, space, minus, apostrophe, dot and @.
Forbidden should be <>;_#*+!"§$%&/()=?{[]}

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can match against latin characters

```
[\p{L}\s\-@\.]*
```